# Getting null value to a variable after async method flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm getting null value in flutter build method for this code.

```
  String userEmail;
  var data;
  String userName;
  @override
  void initState(){
      setState(() {
        getUserName();
        print(userName);
      });
    super.initState();
  }

  void getUserName() async {
    MyFirebaseAuth myFirebaseAuth = MyFirebaseAuth();
    userEmail =await myFirebaseAuth.getUser();
    if (userEmail == null){
      print("no user");
    }
    else{
      data =await fb.firestore().collection('users').doc(userEmail).get().then((onValue){
        return onValue.data();
      });
      print(data);
      print(data['name']);
      userName = data['name'];
      print("Username is $userName");
    }
  }
```

output is

Performing hot restart...

Restarted application in 759ms.
null
{entries: 3, name: xmr}
vraj
Username is xmr

Comment: can you please show us `MyFirebaseAuth` ? and try to remove setState from the initstate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getUserName is future so the method should be

```
Future<void>getUserName() async {
MyFirebaseAuth myFirebaseAuth = MyFirebaseAuth();
userEmail =await myFirebaseAuth.getUser();
if (userEmail == null){
  print("no user");
}
else{
  data =await fb.firestore().collection('users').doc(userEmail).get().then((onValue){
    return onValue.data();
  });
  print(data);
  print(data['name']);
  userName = data['name'];
  print("Username is $userName");
}
}
```

And also make sure to use setState inside the getUserName() instead of initState